# Django: Serving admin media files

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I am trying to serve static files from another domain (sub domain of current domain).
To serve all media files I used this settings:

> MEDIA_URL =
>   'http://media.bud-inform.co.ua/'

So when in template I used

> {{ MEDIA_URL }}

it was replace with the setting above. Now I am trying to serve admin media files from the same subdomain, I changed the settings this way:

> ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX =
>   'http://media.bud-inform.co.ua/admin_media/',

and expected that all calls to media from my admin site will be made to this url.... But actually it didn't work this way, I still see paths to CSS made as following:

> http://bud-inform.co.ua/media/css/login.css

Could you suggest how to serve admin media files correctly

Comment: Seems strange. It should work.

Comment: Yes...Really works, was caching...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MEDIA_URL` and `ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX` are two different things. One is the location of *your* media files, while the other is the location of the django admin system's media files.

You have to make sure that the `ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX` points to somewhere where you're **actually** serving the admin media. Django doesn't handle that step for you.

The django admin media is at `django/contrib/admin/media/`. Copy or symlink that directory somewhere publicly visible and set `ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX` to reflect where you put it.

Comment: Yes that directory is definitely visible from  ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX url.
The problem is that: ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = 'http://media.bud-inform.co.ua/admin%5Fmedia/',

And in admin I see paths like this: http://bud-inform.co.ua/media/css/login.css, when expected to see something like 

http://media.bud-inform.co.ua/admin%5Fmedia/css/login.css',